# Possible weird comment bug

Tags: support, comments, edits

Now I have this bug which shows up occasionally. It prevents me from editing my comments. While I have only seen the bug on Stack Overflow, I think that is because I use Stack Overflow the most. It may also be present in other Stack Exchange websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit comments later than five minutes after they've been posted. Comments have no 'revision history' like questions and answers, so it's important that they stay more or less the same, to prevent confusion.

Comment: Then it's not a bug. Didn't know that.

Comment: Which bug? You should try this (^) comment; you'll be able to edit it for a few more minutes.

Comment: ok. I don't think it is a bug now.

Comment: Me neither. And @Oded agrees with us.

Comment: [Unless you are a mod](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135649/267099)